# Python PIP Install Issues

Tags: python, pip

I am using the command line to try to install pip.  I am using the command line to install the file.  I am using the command "python C:\Users\Lucas\Desktop\get-pip.py install" in the C:\Python27 directory.  Below is the error message i receive in the error log:

```
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\lucas\appdata\local\temp\unpacker-hpeuf5-scratchdir\pip\basecommand.py", line 134, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "c:\users\lucas\appdata\local\temp\unpacker-hpeuf5-scratchdir\pip\commands\install.py", line 236, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
  File "c:\users\lucas\appdata\local\temp\unpacker-hpeuf5-scratchdir\pip\req.py", line 1077, in prepare_files
    url = finder.find_requirement(req_to_install, upgrade=self.upgrade)
  File "c:\users\lucas\appdata\local\temp\unpacker-hpeuf5-scratchdir\pip\index.py", line 265, in find_requirement
    raise DistributionNotFound('No distributions at all found for %s' % req)
DistributionNotFound: No distributions at all found for install
```

Comment: Check this... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-to-install-pip-on-windows

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
cd C:\Users\Lucas\Desktop
python get-pip.py
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not pass any parameters:

```
python get-pip.py
```

or

```
/path/to/version/python get-pip.py
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```
sudo python get-pip.py
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing all these activities using python3 and pip3. That worked for me

Answer (score 0):

The install command is unnecassary, as others pointed on, switch to get-pip.py directory and run command `python get-pip.py` would be enough.

The error indicates that the pip tries to install something with the install command and it does not find the requirement of package name to be installed.
This install or upgrade you can do once pip gets installed.

The command `python \path\to\getpip\get-pip.py` will take care of installing pip with python. Once this step is completed you could try install or upgrade command like `pip install <pkgname>`